# Limit with Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

I’m currently doing some math qualifiers to practice. I came across a problem in the 2000 fall exam at Purdue University that I honestly don’t know how to solve. The problem is the following:

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\{f_n \}$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_1\in L^1(\mu)$ and $$\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>\lambda\}\leq \mu(\{x\in X: |f_1(x)|>\lambda\}),$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$ and all $\lambda>0$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_X \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |f_j(x)|d\mu=0.$$

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think my argument works, do you find any gap about it?

Comment: Not at all. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\int_{X}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|f_{j}(x)|d\mu&\leq\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{X}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|f_{j}(x)|1_{|f_{j}|>\lambda}d\mu+\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{X}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|f_{j}(x)|1_{|f_{j}|\leq\lambda}d\mu\\
&\leq\dfrac{\lambda\mu(X)}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{X}|f_{j}(x)|d\mu_{j},~~~~d\mu_{j}=1_{|f_{j}|>\lambda}d\mu,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\int_{X}|f_{j}(x)|d\mu_{j}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu_{j}(\{|f_{j}|>\alpha\})d\alpha\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu_{1}(\{|f_{1}|>\alpha\})d\alpha\\
&=\int_{X}|f_{1}|d\mu_{1}\\
&=\int_{X}|f_{1}|1_{|f_{1}|>\lambda}d\mu
\end{align*}
as $f_{1}\in L^{1}(\mu)$, the previous term tends to zero as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$. The rest is clear.